# iOS Camera-Based Barcode Scanner via URL

Tags: ios, html, camera, barcode

How can I read linear (one-dimensional, such as Code 128) barcodes using the camera on an iOS device from a web page?

Essentially, I suppose I'm looking for a free barcode scanner app that I can install on an iPad but that can be used by my web app. I want to launch the barcode scanner from the web browser and then receive the scanned data. How does this process look on iOS? Does the barcode scanner app need to support a callback scheme like `someProtocol://scanBarcode?callback=http://example.com/scan.do%3Fscanned=` so it can "relaunch" my web app? Are there other ways to accomplish this type of data transfer/interaction between web apps and native apps on iOS?

Comment: your idea should work, but AFAIK there is no existing app that provide such interaction. you may have to write the barcode scanner app on your own.

Answer (score 2):

In the same way that it supports Android, the free and open source [Zxing Barcode Scanner on iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/barcodes-scanner/id417257150?mt=8) version 1.1 now supports web-based scanning with a URL callback.

```
zxing://scan/?ret=http%3A%2F%2Ffoo.com%2Fproducts%2F%7BCODE%7D%2Fdescription&SCAN_FORMATS=UPC_A,EAN_13
```

Simply [use a `zxing://scan/` URL](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningFromWebPages) with `{CODE}` as a placeholder in the callback URL. For example, the above example would load `http://foo.com/products/01234/description` if the barcode *01234* were scanned.

**Unfortunately, only QR codes are supported in version 1.1.**

Answer (score 0):

For UPC/EAN and QR, there is the free iOS (and Android) app "pic2shop" (developed by my company) with the following signature (the string EAN is replaced by the barcode content):

```
pic2shop://scan?callback=YOURURL%3A//EAN
```

For other symbologies, the paid version "pic2shop pro" has the following url:

```
p2spro://scan?formats=EAN13,EAN8,UPCE,ITF,CODE39,CODE128,CODE93,STD2OF5,CODABAR,QR&callback=CALLBACK_URL
```

There is more detailed info on the app's website.